# Qt WebEngine 5.6 Recipe do_install

Tags: qt, sed, embedded-linux, yocto, qtwebengine

I found these lines in the [Qt WebEngine 5.5 and 5.6 recipe](https://github.com/meta-qt5/meta-qt5/blob/master/recipes-qt/qt5/qtwebengine_git.bb)

To make Qt Web Engine compile for 5.6, I needed to delete these lines.  Since I have no idea why qtwebengine-qmlplugins, qtwebengine-plugins, and qtwebengine-examples are all gone from the build. So when these lines try to remove the files from the plugin directories. It returns error.

Could someone explain what do they mean? especially the `sed` one. And what happened to the Qtwebengine plugins, qmlplugins and examples in Qt WebEngine 5.6?

```
do_install_append() {
    rmdir ${D}${OE_QMAKE_PATH_PLUGINS}/${BPN} ${D}${OE_QMAKE_PATH_PLUGINS} || true
    sed -i 's@ -Wl,--start-group.*-Wl,--end-group@@g; s@-L${B}[^ ]* @ @g' ${D}${libdir}/pkgconfig/Qt5WebEngineCore.pc
}
```

**Edit**: This is the error from compiling

```
ERROR: Function failed: do_install (log file is located at /mountdata/hio-yocto-bsp/qt5jethro/qt5/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtwebengine/5.5.99+5.6.0-rc+gitAUTOINC+3f02c25de4_779a2388fc-r0/temp/log.do_install.3412)
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /mountdata/hio-yocto-bsp/qt5jethro/qt5/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtwebengine/5.5.99+5.6.0-rc+gitAUTOINC+3f02c25de4_779a2388fc-r0/temp/log.do_install.3412
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_install
| NOTE: make -j 32 MAKEFLAGS=-j 32 OE_QMAKE_COMPILER=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -march=armv7-a -mthumb-interwork -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=neon -mtune=cortex-a9 --sysroot=/mountdata/hio-yocto-bsp/qt5jethro/qt5/tmp/sysroots/hio-imx6dl-board OE_QMAKE_CC=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -march=armv7-a -mthumb-interwork -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=neon -mtune=cortex-a9 --sysroot=/mountdata/hio-yocto-bsp/qt5jethro/qt5/tmp/sysroots/hio-imx6dl-board OE_QMAKE_CXX=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++  -march=armv7-a -mthumb-interwork -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=neon -mtune=cortex-a9 --sysroot=/mountdata/hio-yocto-bsp/qt5jethro/qt5/tmp/sysroots/hio-imx6dl-board OE_QMAKE_CFLAGS= -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types OE_QMAKE_CXXFLAGS= -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types -fvisibility-inlines-hidden OE_QMAKE_LINK=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++  -march=armv7-a -mthumb-interwork -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=neon -mtune=cortex-a9 --sysroot=/mountdata/hio-yocto-bsp/qt5jethro/qt5/tmp/sysroots/hio-imx6dl-board OE_QMAKE_LDFLAGS=-Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=gnu -Wl,--as-needed OE_QMAKE_AR=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-ar OE_QMAKE_STRIP=echo OE_QMAKE_WAYLAND_SCANNER=/mountdata/hio-yocto-bsp/qt5jethro/qt5/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin/wayland-scanner OE_QMAKE_INCDIR_QT=/mountdata/hio-yocto-bsp/qt5jethro/qt5/tmp/sysroots/hio-imx6dl-board//usr/include/qt5 install INSTALL_ROOT=/mountdata/hio-yocto-bsp/qt5jethro/qt5/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtwebengine/5.5.99+5.6.0-rc+gitAUTOINC+3f02c25de4_779a2388fc-r0/image
| make: Nothing to be done for `install'.
| rmdir: failed to remove '/mountdata/hio-yocto-bsp/qt5jethro/qt5/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtwebengine/5.5.99+5.6.0-rc+gitAUTOINC+3f02c25de4_779a2388fc-r0/image/usr/lib/qt5/plugins/qtwebengine': No such file or directory
| rmdir: failed to remove '/mountdata/hio-yocto-bsp/qt5jethro/qt5/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtwebengine/5.5.99+5.6.0-rc+gitAUTOINC+3f02c25de4_779a2388fc-r0/image/usr/lib/qt5/plugins': No such file or directory
| sed: can't read /mountdata/hio-yocto-bsp/qt5jethro/qt5/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtwebengine/5.5.99+5.6.0-rc+gitAUTOINC+3f02c25de4_779a2388fc-r0/image/usr/lib/pkgconfig/Qt5WebEngineCore.pc: No such file or directory
| WARNING: exit code 2 from a shell command.
| ERROR: Function failed: do_install (log file is located at /mountdata/hio-yocto-bsp/qt5jethro/qt5/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtwebengine/5.5.99+5.6.0-rc+gitAUTOINC+3f02c25de4_779a2388fc-r0/temp/log.do_install.3412)
ERROR: Task 1523 (/mountdata/hio-yocto-bsp/qt5jethro/sources/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/qt5/qtwebengine_git.bb, do_install) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 5404 tasks of which 5363 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.
No currently running tasks (5404 of 5417)
```

**Edit**: I found out that there is an extra `/` `.../hio-imx6dl-board//usr/include...`.  I have removed the `/` in `OE_QMAKE_INCDIR_QT='${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}/${OE_QMAKE_PATH_HEADERS}'`  but still get the same error above.

```
OE_QMAKE_INCDIR_QT=/mountdata/hio-yocto-bsp/qt5jethro/qt5/tmp/sysroots/hio-imx6dl-board//usr/include/qt5 install INSTALL_ROOT=/mountdata/hio-yocto-bsp/qt5jethro/qt5/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtwebengine/5.5.99+5.6.0-rc+gitAUTOINC+3f02c25de4_779a2388fc-r0/image
```

Comment: Could you share your the logs from the  failed build? To me, it looks like neither of the two lines in `do_install_append()` ought to make the build fail.

Comment: I have added the log.  You could see that it failed at rmdir and sed. which is from the do_install_append().  Again, qmlplugins and plugins as well as qtwebengine libraries are absent from the 5.6 builds.

Comment: Oh, I just realized that the make "install" failed, too...What is happening here..?

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs due to missing dbus, multiple solutions possible:

1. Add dbus to your image.
2. Add line to qtwebengine_git.bb: `DEPENDS += "dbus"`